# Ubuntu 14.0.4 OpenVPN connection - username and password only

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to set up a VPN SSL connection that uses just username and password. I'm setting it up in OpenVPN with Network Manager.

I enter the gateway, type=password, username and password.

However the 'save' button is greyed out until I enter a certificate.

How can I set up a connection with only username and password?

Thanks

Matthew

Comment: I'd like to add that I've looked this up but nothing helps me get past the greyed out save button.

Comment: You are intentionally decreasing security since you have now way of verifying the server or client as being who they claim they are. This is a BAD idea

Answer (score 0):

Change the VPN type from "*SSL/TLS + User Auth*" to "*User Auth*" and then it does not require certs for clients.

Comment: How do you change VPN type??